# jquery, .append function dosen't transport the parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the jQuery and JavaScript on my code but not availiable next the code.

```
$('#thumbnails').append("<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/"+in_video_id+"/default.jpg' class='thumb'/>");                          
$('#thumbnails').html("<button onclick='read()'>Play</button>");
```

->it's availiable. my meaning is the my function(read()) can it's role.

```
$('#thumbnails').append("<img src='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/"+in_video_id+"/default.jpg' class='thumb'/>");                          
$('#thumbnails').html("<button onclick='read(imparameter)'>Play</button>");
```

->but this is not availiable. i don't know why this parameter don't going the function(read())..

what's wrong/???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `imparameter` is a javascript variable that holds the value, in that case you need to use string concatenation

```
$('#thumbnails').html('<button onclick="read(\'' + imparameter + '\')">Play</button>');
```

Comment: very thanks! you are right. my case is imparameter is javascript varaible that holds the value. but i can't understand why i have to add the \' on the imprameter's side. because imparameter is not string. just javascript variable!